# SOAP: How to Make Call to CountryInfoService WSDL file in Java e.g. use CapitalCity SOAP Operation

Tags: java, api, web-services, soap, soap-client

Hi so I managed to generate WSDL Java Classes using Java-WS with the "**wsimport**" command. The WSDL file is from:

```
http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?wsdl
```

[image]

The problem is that Im not familiar on how to use this.
How do I make a SOAP call to the CapitalCity SOAP method.

In SOAPUI, you would just pass the **CountryISOCode** like:

```
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:CapitalCity>
         <web:sCountryISOCode>UKR</web:sCountryISOCode>
      </web:CapitalCity>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to do this in Java?
This is my code that I've started.

```
CountryInfoService countryInfoService = new CountryInfoService();
```

I dont know what follows next. Again Im trying to use the "**CapitalCity**" SOAP Operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample answer:

```
    CountryInfoService countryInfoService = new CountryInfoService();
    CountryInfoServiceSoapType countryInfoServiceSoapType = countryInfoService.getCountryInfoServiceSoap();
    System.out.println(countryInfoServiceSoapType.capitalCity("RUS"));
    //output is 'Moscow'
```

That's how to use it.